# The same user input leads to different output in my while loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with my code below.

When I enter choice 1 it asks me to enter IATA code and displays the output I expect, however if I again enter choice 1 the control goes to invalid IATA code even if I enter a valid one.

If I enter different choice other than 1 and 2 it should display invalid choice but it does not.

I can't see why this happens, can anyone help?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class AirportCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.print("Enter input file name >>");
    String fname = sc.next();
    File fp = new File("E:/task.txt");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(fp);
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != 2) {
        System.out.println("AirPort Finder");
        System.out.println("1. Enter Airport");
        System.out.println("2. Close");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        if (choice == 2) {
            break;
        } else if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter IATA code >>");
            String code = sc.next();
            kb.useDelimiter(",");
            boolean check = false;
            if (code.length() == 3) {
                while (kb.hasNextLine()) {
                    String icode = kb.next();
                    String apcode = kb.next();
                    String icode1 = kb.next();
                    String apcode1 = kb.nextLine();

                    if (icode.contains(code)) {
                        check = true;
                        System.out.println(icode1 + " " + apcode1);
                    }
                    if (icode1.contains(code)) {
                        check = true;
                        System.out.println(icode + " " + apcode);
                    }
                }
                if (check == false) System.out.println("Invalid IATA code");
            } else System.out.println("Invalid IATA code");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid menu choice");
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Mr.Sumit Singh..as I already mentioned . When I enter choice other than 1 & 2 it should display invalid choice and continue with the loop.
One more problem is when I enter choice 1 it takes the input and displays the output perfectly. It again asks me to enter choice. if i enter choice 1 it says invalid "iata code" ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question came to me in a review queue for help and improvement.  I've tried to make it a little more readable and in particular have edited the title to make it a bit more descriptive and potentially attract people who can help you.  You might want to read through [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get some tips on ways to ask questions that can get you maximum help around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i again enter choice 1 the control goes to invalid iata code

Your problem is that the Scanner you use to check for valid IATA codes in the file (`kb`) is exhausted after the first time you use it.

If you use a `Scanner` to get input from a `File`, once you've been through it once, `kb.hasNextLine()` will always be false.  So, the second time you try option `1`, the checking loop (`while(kb.hasNextLine())`) is never entered.

You have two options - create the `Scanner` for the file within the outer `while` loop so you get a new one each time, or read the data from the file into some local data type so that you can go through it multiple times.

> If i enter different choice other than 1 and 2. it should display invalid choice

Your invalid menu choice text never shows up because it is outside the `while (choice != 2)` loop.  Therefore, you'll only see it when you enter the option 2 and break out of the loop.  You should move it up one level (i.e. above the curly brace immediately before it).

Comment: Hi Mr.J Richard Snape have you made any changes to my code or is it still the same because I have copied the code and compiled it in Net Beans. After giving choice 1 and entering the Airport code it shows invalid IATA code. It is not searching in the input file.. 
          You said read the data from the file into some local data type I don't know how to do it. Can you please help me where to modify my code?. Regards

Comment: No, I haven't changed your code at all as that would change the substance of the question. You can [click the edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29604170/revisions) to see what changed on any edit. If the downloaded and compiled code does something different to the original, then you have a typo in the code you posted. You ask for help to modify the code - that's what's in the answer. If you can't see how to store the data from file in (e.g.) an `ArrayList`, did you try my suggestion of moving the creation of `Scanner kb = new Scanner(...` inside the `while` loop?

Comment: Sir, did you told me to put the last print statement above three curly braces from last. Second time I enter choice 1 it shows the output as well as last print statement. If I put last print statement above two curly braces it gives me correct output Sir. Thank you very much Sir

Comment: So you have it working now? If my answer helped, the best thing to do is to mark it "accepted" so that others can see that it solved the problem. See [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/261369) for how to do that.

Comment: Mr.Richard Vote  when I try vote up your answer.  It says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" to me. I marked it accepted. Thank you very much Sir

Comment: You're welcome.  You won't be able to vote until you get 15 reputation - you will get that quite soon if you continue to use the site and ask nice questions :)  Thank you for accepting the answer - that in itself will have given you 2 more reputation.  Good luck :)

Comment: Hmm - that's a bit weird, unaccepting my answer and accepting the other, based on the conversation above.  Did that answer really solve your problem?  Is there an issue with my answer that you need me to address?

Comment: Mr.Richar I have one more problem with the second while loop. The output is coming as I expected but there is little bit error in the output.

Comment: There is nothing with your answer Mr.Richard this is another question I'm asking you. I want to ask you in personal but I don't know how to do it. First I thought of asking two questions at the same time but second question is about input file and its output.  I'm sorry for my manners Sir,

Comment: OK. No problem.  Here's what to do:  If my answer is the one that solves the problem - mark it as accepted again. If the other answer is better, leave that marked. I don't know if this is what you're trying to do, but you'll only get your 2 rep once per question. If you have another question - ask it as a new question on the site. Then, anyone can answer it if they know how, you can again accept the best answer (another 2 rep when you do) and you can post a link here so that, if I have time, I can try to answer. Don't try to ask questions direct to individuals here - it's against site policy.

Comment: I'm sorry Mr.Richard I won't repeat it again as this is my first question in stackoverflow. I'm really sorry I finally marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i can see it you should wrap the last System.out.println...the one for the Invalid menu choice with an else-block...as you do it now you will go to that line no matter if you enter 1, 2 or any other number, because this line is AFTER your if-else block and not part of it.
I hope this helps.
Regards